# (pure) C: строки в полях односвязанного списка

Tags: c, строки, list

список:

```
struct list
{
    char row[255];
    struct list *ptr;   
};
```

Хочу его инициализировать и добавить новый элемент:

```
/*
    INIT list (Editor)
*/
struct list *init(char text[255]){
    struct list  *lst;  
    lst = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(struct list));

    //char t[255]  = "ssfsefsefsef"; тоже не работает

    lst->row = text; // ОШИБКА
    lst->ptr = NULL;

    return lst;
}
```

В итоге я получаю ошибку:

> [Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[255]' from
>   type 'char *'

При этом даже если вручную присвоить строку `("текст")` или массив '`char[255]`', то тоже эта ошибка.

Но с типом

> int

все работает!

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как использовать строку (массив символов) в списках?**

Спасибо

Comment: Копируйте содержимое, например [strncpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy)

Comment: Что означает комментарий `// char t[255]  = "ssfsefsefsef"; тоже не работает`? Что там у вас "не работает"?

Comment: Кто такой `(pure) C`?

Comment: Я присваивал значение массива через "=" переменной, а через  strncpy работает.
Pure C - это "С" как С++ только С 
Я увидел в одной статье, что язык "Си" называют pure C и не словечко понарвилось.
Извините, если ввсел в заблуждение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В языке С тип "массив" является некопируемым типом. Объекты типа "массив" невозможно присваивать друг другу. Если вы хотите скопировать содержимое одного массива в другой массив, то для этого вам придется либо пользоваться библиотечной функцией копирования памяти (`memcpy`, `strcpy` и т.п.), либо выполнять копирование поэлементно вручную явным циклом.
2. Размер массива в объявлении параметра `char text[255]` не играет никакой роли и игнорируется языком. Нет никакого смысла его там указывать. А вот правильная константность вашему параметру не помешала бы

   ```
   struct list *init(const char text[])
   ```
3. Явное приведение типа результата `malloc` - бессмысленное действие. Также не ясно, почему вы используете присваивание там, где прекрасно подошла бы инициализация

   ```
   struct list *lst = malloc(sizeof *lst);
   ```

Comment: Можно тем не менее сделать финт ушами, а именно объявить структуру с единственным полем — массивом. Тогда всё будет работать с копированием :)